# SVG Detect Onclick events on "fill: none"

Tags: svg

When I create an svg rect with `fill: black`, my `onclick` event handler gets called.

When I replace the `fill: black` with `fill: none`, my event handler is NOT called when I click inside the rect, but only called when I click on the **border** of the rect.

What do I need to change so that click events are detected for clicking **inside** the rectangle?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is controlled by the [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property. Looks like you want to set it to visible

`<rect pointer-events="visible" ...>`