# How can I draw a "transparent stroke" with Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, raphael, stroke

I am attempting to draw the path of a graph so that the path is transparent and the rest of the canvas is not. This way I can use the canvas as a mask and fill the path with different colors using html elements. Kind of like this:

> [image]

Comment: Maybe this will work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042550/svg-fill-color-transparency-alpha

Comment: I'm not a Raphaeljs expert but you can check `stroke-opacity` on [documentation page](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr).

Comment: Yeah, the problem is filling the rest of the paper (minus the path) with a solid color.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to achieve this natively through Raphael, but it could be accomplished by some selective modification of the SVG produced by Raphael.  Consider the use of a [mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) applied to the path.  This technique is used to absolutely delicious visual effect [here](http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog_media/svg_mask.html).

Don't forget that you can access the DOM node associated with a Raphael paper object through that paper object's `canvas` property (I don't know why Baranovskiy chose such a misleading name!).  You could use this to interact directly with the SVG in the DOM, though I can't vouch for interactions between Raphael and custom modifications =)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kevin! I'm not doing too much heavy lifting with Raphael anyway, so I can probably stick to SVG. Not supporting IE in this application anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

To fill only the outer part of a path, you will have to draw what is often called a "donut" made of two path strings.

You will find a good example here : [How to achieve 'donut holes' with paths in Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349651/how-to-achieve-donut-holes-with-paths-in-raphael) .

The idea is:
* give the outer path string as a large counter clockwise closed rectangle, telling the browser that what has to be filled is what is inside
* concat the inner path string as the clockwise closed path you want, telling the browser what has to be filled is what is outside.

Thus resulting in a filled shape with a hole which is the intersection of both filled shapes.