# Own colour range for Sankey Diagram with networkD3 package in R

Tags: r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to plot Sankey diagrams using `sankeyNetwork()` in networkD3 package.

```
sankeyNetwork(Links = Flow_data, Nodes = Nodes_data,
    Source = "Source_ID", Target = "Target",
    Value = "value", NodeID = "Nodes_name",
    width = 1000, height=600, fontsize = 16, nodeWidth = 50,
    colourScale = "d3.scale.category20c()")
```

The visualization works great but I would like to change the colour range to an individual range. Is there any chance to change the colours of the SankeyNetwork? I need a range of only e.g. 3 colours which I can set by myself (not the predefined colourScales of d3.scale).

Answer (score 8):

You can config:

```
sankeyNetwork(Links = Flow_data, Nodes = Nodes_data,
                      Source = "Source_ID", Target = "Target",
                      Value = "value", NodeID = "Nodes_name",
                      width = 1000, height=600, fontsize = 16, nodeWidth = 50,
                      colourScale = "d3.scale.category20c()")  <==== Categorical color
```

**UPDATE**

> Newer version:

```
d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#7d3945","#e0677b", "#244457"])
now works if changed to:
d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#7d3945","#e0677b", "#244457"])
```

Thanks @Peter Ellis

**UPDATE**

> Is there any way to set transparency when using custom colours?
>
> "#AARRGGBB" doesn't seem to work

You can make a selectAll("your_class").style("opacity",0.5), Take a look to this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/6042550/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042550/svg-fill-color-transparency-alpha) for style attribute options. And CSS3 has a fully standardized solution: "fill="rgba(124,240,10,0.5)"

For color references, look here: http://bl.ocks.org/aaizemberg/78bd3dade9593896a59d

and here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors

Comment: Thank you :) I visited these links already. But with the categorical colours I get 10 or 20 predefined colours. I would prefer to use less colours. Is there a possibility to pick only a few of the categorical colours?

Comment: According documentation:  **colourScale character string specifying the categorical colour scale for the nodes**. You can try this:

`"#7d3945","#e0677b", "#244457" `
or 
`d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#7d3945","#e0677b", "#244457"])` <== personal colors

Comment: Hi Klaujesi, do you mind taking a look at a related networkD3 question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280218/r-networkd3-package-node-coloring-in-simplenetwork

Comment: Is there any way to set transparency when using custom colours? #AARRGGBB doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can make a selectAll("your_class").style("opacity",0.5), Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042550/svg-fill-color-transparency-alpha for style attribute options. And CSS3 has a fully standardized solution: "fill="rgba(124,240,10,0.5)"

Comment: Should this answer still work?  Doesn't work for me any more, wondering if something has changed.  When I add colourScale = "d3.scale.category20c()" to sankeyNetwork it no longer draws the diagram.

Comment: d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#7d3945","#e0677b", "#244457"]) now works if changed to d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#7d3945","#e0677b", "#244457"])

Comment: if change to image?