# Create group and change node and links color in an interactive Sankey with the networkD3

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

How can I create a group for nodes and links and color them accordingly on Sankey plots using networkD3 in R? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132423/creating-a-sankey-diagram-using-networkd3-package-in-r) excellent example shows the steps on data formatting.
Here is the code and plot from the example there, I want to add color by groups in this plot.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = '
name  year1           year2         year3           year4
Bob   Hilton          Sheraton      Westin          Hyatt
John  "Four Seasons"  Ritz-Carlton  Westin          Sheraton
Tom   Ritz-Carlton    Westin        Sheraton        Hyatt
Mary  Westin          Sheraton      "Four Seasons"  Ritz-Carlton
Sue   Hyatt           Ritz-Carlton  Hilton          Sheraton
Barb  Hilton          Sheraton      Ritz-Carlton    "Four Seasons"
')
```

Format dataframe and create Sankey plot

```
links <-
  df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column", values_to = "source") %>%  # gather all columns
  mutate(column = match(column, names(df))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = column)) %>%  # get target from following node in row
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(target))  # remove links from last column in original data
links <-
  links %>%
  mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', column)) %>%
  mutate(target = paste0(target, '_', column + 1)) %>%
  select(source, target)
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))
nodes$label <- sub('_[0-9]*$', '', nodes$name) # remove column id from node label
links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
links$value <- 1

library(networkD3)

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source_id',
              Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'label')
```

##### How to create a group and change node and links colors by the group in the about Sankey plot ?

Comment: See if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616321/modify-networkd3-sankey-plot-with-user-defined-colors). It's about 5 years old, so things may have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to the `links` and to the `nodes` data frames that specify the group of each row, then specify those columns with the `LinkGroup` and `NodeGroup` (respectively) arguments of `sankeyNetwork()`.

For example, using your code/data above, I add a `link_group` column to the `links` data frame and a `node_group` column to the `nodes` data frame, and then specify them in the call to `sankeyNetwork()`...

```r
links <- links %>% mutate(link_group = sub(".*_", "", source))
nodes <- nodes %>% mutate(node_group = sub(".*_", "", name))

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source_id',
              Target = 'target_id', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'label',
              LinkGroup = "link_group", NodeGroup = "node_group")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @CJ Yetman but how i can make each group a unique color? ie.  a different color for each nodes and links ?

Comment: They are different, for each group. ?

Comment: If you want to assign a unique group for each unique node, then each node will have a unique color because it will be in a unique group.

Comment: Yes, different person different color.  One color for Tom other for Bob and so on.

Comment: You could also use the link name and the source name as the group columns, and if they are unique, then the groups/colors will be unique too, e.g. `LinkGroup = "source", NodeGroup = "name"`.

Comment: can you help me with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74281705/5959719