# Create shiny app with selected Sankey node and links

Tags: r, shiny, sankey-diagram, networkd3

Following up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269084/create-group-and-change-node-and-links-color-in-an-interactive-sankey-with-the-n/74280857?noredirect=1#comment131141778_74280857) question, how can I create an shiny app in which I can choose a person and get nodes and links related to that person only shown?.
The data plot and code I tried are below:

##### Data

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = '
name  year1           year2         year3           year4
Bob   Hilton          Sheraton      Westin          Hyatt
John  "Four Seasons"  Ritz-Carlton  Westin          Sheraton
Tom   Ritz-Carlton    Westin        Sheraton        Hyatt
Mary  Westin          Sheraton      "Four Seasons"  Ritz-Carlton
Sue   Hyatt           Ritz-Carlton  Hilton          Sheraton
Barb  Hilton          Sheraton      Ritz-Carlton    "Four Seasons"
')
```

##### Sankey plot

```
library(networkD3)
links <-
  df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%  # add a row id
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "column", values_to = "source") %>%  # gather all columns
  mutate(column = match(column, names(df))) %>%  # convert col names to col ids
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = lead(source, order_by = column)) %>%  # get target from following node in row
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(target))  # remove links from last column in original data
links <-
  links %>%
  mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', column)) %>%
  mutate(target = paste0(target, '_', column + 1)) %>%
  select(source, target)
nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))
nodes$label <- sub('_[0-9]*$', '', nodes$name) # remove column id from node label
links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
links$value <- 1

sankeyNetwork(Links = links,
                Nodes = nodes,
                Source = 'source_id',
                Target = 'target_id',
                Value = 'value',
                NodeID = 'label',
                LinkGroup = "source",
                NodeGroup = "name",
                fontSize = 20,
                nodeWidth = 10)
```

#### Unsuccessful shiny app code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "name",
              label   = "name",
              choices =  c("Bob", "John","Tom","Mary","Sue","Barb")),
  
  sankeyNetworkOutput("diagram")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  links <- links
  links
  nodes <- nodes
  nodes
  
  links2 <-reactive({
    links %>%
      filter(source ==df$name )
  })
  

  output$diagram <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    sankeyNetwork(
      Links = links2,
      Nodes = nodes,
      Source = 'source_id',
      Target = 'target_id',
      Value = 'value',
      NodeID = 'label',
      LinkGroup = "source",
      NodeGroup = "name",
      fontSize = 20,
      nodeWidth = 10,
      sinksRight = FALSE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the siney app, I want to select the person and see the sanky diagram related to that person only i,e, choose all nodes and links related to that person. For example, it will be something like picture below for "Tom".

[image].