# Creating a transparent color within a string palette

Tags: transparency, google-earth-engine, color-palette

I am working within Google Earth Engine and am trying to create a no-color/completely transparent color (no boarder and no fill).  Below is a line of code where the first color should be the transparent "color".  Basically I want my min value to not show up in the map at all.

```
    Map.addLayer(image, {min: 0, max: 3, palette: [transparent, '#0571b0', '#FFDF00', '#ca0020']},'image');
```

I have tried creating a variable to set a color as completely transparent (change the opacity to 0), but the `palette` command cannot take variables.  Only strings.  [I've also read SVG fill color transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042550/svg-fill-color-transparency-alpha), but do not understand how to change the opacity of that specific color without creating a variable (which again, `palette` doesn't allow). Lastly, I tried adding 00 to the end of another color, but that did not work either.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**
I was never able to find a solution to this and ended up just going with a white back ground. It was purely for a nicer aesthetic look to allow a basemap to be seen. If I ever come across a solution, I'll be sure to post it.

Comment: I don't have a dev environment to try but if they are CSS colors - can you try rgba()?

i.e., rgba(0,0,0,0)

Comment: so would `rgba(0,0,0,0)` replace the transparent text?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would try - just because that syntax has been around a lot longer than the hex with alpha you tried (#0000 - shorthand).

So I'd try:
`Map.addLayer(image, {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', '#0571b0', '#FFDF00', '#ca0020']},'image');`

Just one last note - rgba() function notation is supported by all browsers whereas hex with alpha doesn't work in Edge or IE if you happen to be using those...
Ref to css colors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. I found the solution in the developer group.

See the answers: https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/WcxtEIzudxw/m/GscOlsQhDgAJ

The Solution:

// create your previous mask

image = image.eq(1)

// mask and set the opacity

image = image.mask(image.mask().where(image.eq(0),0.0))

Comment: Good find! I'll try and get back into my code and give this a try!